# What makes a selinux-caused EACCESS to not be logged in audit

Tags: linux, selinux, audit

I've got a system with samba running with standard targetted policy for Fedora.

At some point samba is trying to access a directory tagged `unconfined_u:object_r:unlabeled_t:s0` and fails. Through strace I can see:

```
lstat("/data", 0x7ffcabcad570) = -1 EACCES (Permission denied)
```

The basic unix permissions on the directory are 755, so the permission failure is definitely on the selinux side.

I expected this to get logged in audit with other policy violations, but it was not. What can prevent the report in this case?

Comment: `chroot` involved?

Comment: @anx no, no chroot in this config